# Patterns in colored 3x3 squares

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

Could you please give the answer to this puzzle. I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/mensa/comments/e79d93/the_finals/), by [user Kyu on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/---Kyu---/))

Additional insight by Kyu from reddit:

> Shared by Kyu: "Though I will say that [the puzzle] has a slight 'inconsistency' that might throw someone off early. I think I'll keep it the way it is, it's like a puzzle that has degraded a bit but has a perfect answer." ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/mensa/comments/e4bdxb/7_fun_puzzles_to_help_soothe_your_noodly_itch_d/f9l9otp/))

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Where is this puzzle from? We require puzzles to be attributed to the original source, otherwise it could be construed as plagiarism.

Comment: F1Krazy, sorry I am new to this. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: Do we even know what this is asking us to do? I can't figure out what it wants me to solve....

Comment: @NegativeFriction I suspect you have to pick which of the alternatives (1 through 6) fits into the lower-right-hand corner of the grid on the left to establish a rule through each row or column of the grid.

Comment: What actually we have to solve.. are there any rules..

Comment: @ZanyG that makes so much more sense than everything  was trying to puzzle out. Something tells me I won't be solving this one if I needed help to determine what it was asking in the first place lol

Comment: @NegativeFriction These are the sort of IQ test questions you see all the time on Puzzling. There are plenty of others even in the 'Related Questions' tab here.

Comment: I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 2):

> If the sum of column x in the top two rows of boxes is 4 then the x+1st column (taken mod 9) in the bottom row of boxes is empty; else it contains 2 squares. Thus the answer is 6.[image]

Comment: Can you visualize this answer or demonstrate the steps? I didn't understand your answer at all

Comment: @Adib I edited my answer with a picture.

Comment: How can you tell which of the squares in each column of the bottom boxes are filled? Is it just that only one of the options has the required square count?

Comment: So the Yellow/Greyish doesn't add anything to the problem? Where do you get any clue about shifting by 1? Same numbers mapping to different patterns, and same patterns mapping to different numbers? I'm not a puzzle expert but to me it looks like a crafted solution rather than genuine.

Comment: Agree with @Ignasi, I'm not sure I'm convinced.